# cannot uninstall Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app, I just uninstalled a Cordova plugin this way :

```
$ cordova plugin remove phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

Uninstalling phonegap-facebook-plugin from android

but when I list the plugins it still appears as installed :

```
$ cordova plugins
cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.3 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 4.0.3 "Google+"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.1.1-dev "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.7 "Keyboard"
phonegap-facebook-plugin 0.12.0 "Facebook Connect"
```

Can help me figure this out ?

Thanks

Comment: please check plugin.xml for plugin 'com.ionic.keyboard' is exist or not?

Comment: yes it does : `$ find . -name 'plugin.xml'` gives `./plugins/ionic-plugin-keyboard/plugin.xml`

Comment: Did remove this plugin manually?

Comment: I did the command : $cordova plugin remove

Comment: delete phonegap-facebook-plugin from your plugin folder?

Comment: ok it seems to work thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please delete `phonegap-facebook-plugin` from your `plugin` folder manually.

Comment: I also had to remove it from `plugins/fetch.json`

Answer (score 5):

the problem is you have to use the --save flag when you run the cordova plugin rm command.
cordova plugin remove phonegap-facebook-plugin **--save**

This --save flag tells the compiler to also remove it from config.xml , where all the plugins are listed. When you don't pass the **--save** flag, the plugin entry remains in the config.xml and thus when you run: "cordova plugins ls", your plugin is still there..

This should be highlighted more clearly in the official cordova docs..

Answer (score 1):

You can remove any cordova plugin forcefully by using below command,

```
cordova plugin remove phonegap-facebook-plugin--force
```

then try to remove all platforms using below command,

```
cordova platform remove <platform_name>
```

then try to add platforms again using below command,

```
cordova platform add <platform_name>
```

Finally prepare project using below command,

```
cordova prepare
```

Answer (score 0):

A). You can directly delete plugin from plugin directory.

1. got to project/directory/plugin.
2. Choose plugin you want to delete.
3. Remove from there.

B). On obuntu or mac

```
 1. open terminal (ctrl+t).
 2. $ cd project/directory/plugin.
 3. $ rm -rf plugin-name-to-be-remove.
```

C). Cordova Command

```
 1. $ cd project/directory/plugin.
 2. $  cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-name
```

This may help you..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly delete the plugin from plugin folder or use the 
`cordova plugin remove plugin-name`
You can find the list of plugin by this command `cordova plugin list`

Sometime this make a great issue that the plugin part also remains in the platform folder. So you can remove the platform and add the platform again.