# Cordova: Cannot find plugin.xml

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to remove this plugin from my coordova file and I am getting this issues

```
Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin 'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer'. Please try adding it again.
```

This is the cordova command to remove the plugin

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Please assist on why I cannot be able to remove this plugin. Thank you

Comment: Try to have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30299721/4515566

Answer (score 32):

I ran into this issue while trying to upgrade a plugin.

Start by deleting the plugin folder `<myapp>/plugins/cordova-plugin-file-transfer` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277606/cannot-uninstall-cordova-plugin). If the plugin still cannot be removed via cordova, edit the 3 json files in `<your_app>/plugins` and removed all references to cordova-plugin-file-transfer.

---- removed from android.json ----

```
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {
    "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.mycompany.myapp"
}
```

---- removed from ios.json ----

```
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {
    "PACKAGE_NAME": "com.mycompany.myapp"
}
```

---- removed from fetch.json ----

```
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {
    "source": {
       "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
}
```

Cordova will now recognize that the plugin is not installed. This solved my update issue as I was finally able to run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer` without getting an error.

Answer (score 9):

First, make sure the plugin isn't listed in your config.xml. Then you can reinstall the platform for example for Android you will enter the following in the command line for your project:

`cordova platform remove android`

`cordova platform add android`

Answer (score 9):

In my Ionic app, I was facing this issue with cordova-plugin-android-permissions plugin. Simply **deleting folder of this plugin from plugins folder** solved my issue

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue when building out my app in Ionic 3. The steps I followed to clear this issue include:

1. Check what Cordova Plugins are already installed on the App using -`cordova plugin list` in your CLI
2. Delete any Plugin that are not listed in Step(1) from your Apps **plugins folder** in your applications directory ie.**deleting folder of this plugin from plugins folder**
3. Try and build again.

Comment: You're a legend. I've been pulling my hair out for hours over this.

Answer (score 1):

To add to jshaw.fb's answer, remove those lines from browser.json as well

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error I copy all file from node_module/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio paste it to plugins/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio. Then I remove the plugin and I have added it again.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue too. I removed all platforms first. Then I removed the plugin and re-added the platforms. This method works for me.

```
cordova platform remove android

cordova platform remove ios

cordova plugin rm 'plugin-name'

cordova platform add android

cordova platform add ios
```