# Remove cordova-plugin-file dependency from cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In my project we are not given any functionality to `upload or download file`. So, I don't need `Cordova plugin file` in My project. But `cordova-plugin-advanced-http` has dependency on that.

If I'll remove `cordova plugin` file its **throws the error while make build of android or ios**.

> Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-file". Please try
>   adding it again.

Can anyone suggest me how resolve this error.

Comment: Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517537/cordova-cannot-find-plugin-xml